# AndroidStudio. Rename package in a module

Tags: android, android-studio

Our app contains several modules, which of them have the same package structure: i.E. com.package.app.*

Now I would like to rename a package (and of cause all its subpackages) within only one module without renaming it in another modules. It should be something like com.package.app.* => com.newpackage.app.*

Is there a simple solution for this?

I saw [Android Studio Rename Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package) but the solutions there seem to work for applications with one module.

Thank you in advance

Comment: click the folder shift+f6 and rename the package

Comment: Rename the folder and in your app use ctrl+shift+R to replace old name with new one everywhere in code. 
It is 2 step process this way.

Comment: @Raj the problem is, that android studio also renames packages in other modules

Answer (score 0):

Android studio requires the name of the package to be same for all files in the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have two package names in you application.
However if you are referring to the structure like this:

[image]

Then you will have to right click on the root package and click on new > package

**Right Click > New > package**
and define the name of the directory.